# Этапы работы функции и уровни абстракции

Tags: функции, методы

В следующей книге - "Чистый код. Создание, анализ и рефакторинг" Роберта Мартина утверждается:

> ФУНКЦИЯ ДОЛЖНА ВЫПОЛНЯТЬ ТОЛЬКО ОДНУ ОПЕРАЦИЮ. ОНА ДОЛЖНА ВЫПОЛНЯТЬ ЕЕ ХОРОШО. И НИЧЕГО ДРУГОГО ОНА ДЕЛАТЬ НЕ ДОЛЖНА.

Далее, автор задается вопросом, что значит "одна операция" и дает ответ:

> Если функция выполняет только те **действия, которые находятся на одном
>
>   уровне под объявленным именем функции**, то эта функция выполняет одну операцию.

В примере (ниже), которым автор объясняет **этапы работы функции на одном уровне абстракции под объявленным именем функции** мне не удается ухватить понимание "одного уровня". Условный блок определяет уровень? Логическая последовательность выражений?

```
public static String renderPageWithSetupsAndTeardowns( 
PageData pageData, boolean isSuite) throws Exception { 
if (isTestPage(pageData)) 
   includeSetupAndTeardownPages(pageData. isSuite); 
   return pageData.getHtmlО; 
}
```

> 1. Функция проверяет, является ли страница тестовой страницей.
> 2. Если является, то в нее включаются начальные и конечные блоки.
> 3. Для страницы генерируется код HTML.

Возможно есть более доходчивые примеры или объяснение?

(*Если грамотно выстроенная функция реализуется именно с учетом уровней абстракции (как описывает автор), то это очень важная и глубокая концепция, которую следует понимать.*)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Абстракция данных из [википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85)

> Придание объекту характеристик, которые чётко определяют его
>   концептуальные границы, отличая от всех других объектов.
>
> Основная идея состоит в том, чтобы отделить способ использования
>   составных объектов
>   данных от деталей их реализации в виде более простых объектов, подобно
>   тому, как функциональная абстракция разделяет способ использования
>   функции и деталей её реализации в терминах более примитивных функций,
>   таким образом, данные обрабатываются функцией высокого уровня с
>   помощью вызова функций низкого уровня.

Уровнем абстракции Вы можете разделять своё приложение. Например, Вам нужно сделать страницу отправки форм. У Вас будет:
- Подключение к бд (1 уровень )
- CRUD работа с бд (2 уровень)
- отправка конкретной формы (3 уровень)

То есть у Вас будет 3 уровня и Вам необходимо, допустим, добавить подключение к ещё одной бд, где это реализовать? Естественно, на 1-м уровне. А если необходимо сделать ещё одну форму, то на 3-м.

Уровни абстракции определяете Вы, и поэтому это достаточно сложный процесс. Пример выше является лёгким потому, что он хрестоматийный.

Возьмём Вашу функцию.

Эта функция renderPageWithSetupsAndTeardowns может иметь несколько названий в зависимости от того как Вы построили уровни абстракции.

ПО идее, она должна называться просто renderPage. А разбор и установка, которые являются частью названия, должны быть на другом уровне абстракции (то есть класс, который рендерит страницу может либо иметь родителя, либо содержать объект, который делает разборку сборку html страницы).

*Всё зависит от того как вы декомпозируете задачу. Какие объекты вы выберете за основу. Насколько много у Вас будут простых элементов.*

Answer (score 6):

**Уровень абстракции** - это характеристика ее детализованности.

Т.е. если мы оперерируем обьектом - это *один* уровень абстракции, а если начинаем лезть в его части и оперировать уже ими - это *другой* уровень абстракции, который *ниже* первого.

**Обобщим.** Функция выполняет одну операцию, **если** уровень взаимодействий, которые она выполняет, *одинаков*. Если в одном операторе функция вызывает один обьект, а уже в другом дергает методы его частей, то это **две разные операции**.

Задавайте вопросы, если что непонятно.

Answer (score 3):

По просьбе @TimurVI перевожу комментарий в ответ.

На Ваш вопрос довольно сложно ответить однозначно. Выделение уровней абстракции это искусство. Для описания (и визуализации) систем очень подходит UML. [Цитата](http://www.intuit.ru/studies/professional_retraining/941/courses/229/lecture/5954?page=1): "каждая сущность фокусируется на каком-то определенном аспекте системы и выражает разный уровень абстракции. Другими словами, каждая модель соответствует некоторой определенной, частной точке зрения на проектируемую систему". Или что-нибудь про [уровни абстракции](http://alice.pnzgu.ru:8080/~zsa/sql/titan_zsa/uml_htm_gol/gl_07.htm#a06)

И даже в приведённом примере не всё гладко, например, почему отрисовка занимается проверкой и тем более возвращает строку, а не вызывается непосредственно у объекта? Здесь наблюдаются три действия - проверка, заполнение, кодирование в строку. На мой частный взгляд проверка и заполнение могут быть на одном уровне, а вот кодирование - это совсем другая задача. Вероятно у автора книги более широкие взгляды.

Вообще, довольно распространена проблема раздувания сущностей: авторы кода стараются запихнуть всё что только под руку попадётся в один класс/функцию/цикл/блок кода, видимо считая, что так будет оптимальней или чтобы было в одном месте, не знаю. Но через год, два, а может и неделю эту сущность просто выкидывают - её не прочитать, совершенно непонятно для чего она была нужна. Так вот, основное правило: каждая сущность должна предназначаться для одной цели и  выполнять действия непосредственно связанные с этой целью. Здесь "действия" это не столько методы класса (по сути метод класса тоже сущность), сколько смысл выполняемых инструкций, которые находятся на одном (верхнем) уровне сущности.

Например, отрисовка. Можно слепить нечто принимающее что-то, во что-то конвертирующее, заполняющее некий буфер, преобразующее в строку и пересылающее куда-то и всё это длинной портянкой кода. А можно подумать и сделать сущность отвечающую за приём данных, сущность преобразующую данные в инструкции для отрисовки, сущности которые одну инструкцию преобразуют в картинку (отрисовывают), сущность отрисовки, которая заполняет картинку согласно последовательности инструкций (фактически она не рисует), сущность упаковки результата в нужный формат.

Второй вариант более громоздкий, но каждую из сущностей можно видоизменить, использовать повторно или исключить, по мере развития проекта, а не переписывать всё с нуля.

Или вот. Функция занимается чтением из файла. Читаем код: открыть файл, проверка дескриптора, прочитать данные в буфер, проверка размера, цикл вывода в консоль посимвольно с проверками на видимость, закрыть файл. ТАК! стоп, что здесь делает цикл вывода. Правильно - убрать в другую функцию: печать в консоль. Итого, открыть, читать, печатать, закрыть. Не идеально, но лучше. Почему не идеально? Исходная цель функции - чтение файла, с какого перепугу здесь печать? Что делать? Самое простое изменить цель, самое правильное вынести печать "выше". В конце-концов если наша функция вернёт буфер (или заполнит данный) это не противоречит её цели, а вот что будут дальше делать с этим буфером её не касается.

Answer (score 1):

Точно не помню, но есть подозрение, что тут речь об обращении только к одному уровню ствойств переданных параметров. Т. е. `isTestPage(pageData)` можно, `pageData.getHtmlО` - тоже можно, а какое-нибудь `pageData.smth.inner` - уже нельзя.